# El formulario que esta dentro de un while se guarda dos veces en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

El formulario lo tengo dentro de un ciclo while dentro de un echo para poder resivir los datos de una consulta y luego con un formulario mandarlo a otra tabla en la base de datos pero se guarda dos veces como puedo hacer para que se guarden una sola ves?

```
    <?php
//Mostramos los registros
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo " <table width='100%' align='center' >
      <tr><!--<h2 align='center'>Registro de Empresas</h2>-->
      <td>
      <div class='containere'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
      <form action='' id='formpost' class='formulario'   name='otro' onsubmit='return agregaRegistro();'  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <div class='form-group'>      
     <input type='text'  class='form-control' name='ide' id='ide' value='".$row['id_e']."' >
          </div>
          <div class='form-group'>  
     <input type='text'  class='form-control' name='idp' id='idp' value='".$row['id_p']."' >
          </div>      
           <div class='form-group'>      
     <input type='text'  class='form-control' name='ida' id='ida' value='".$_SESSION['id_a']."'  >
          </div>      
          <div class='form-group' align='right'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='agregar' value='agregar' class='btn btn-primary' >
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
       <div id='cargando'> </div>            
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
}
mysql_free_result($result)
?>
```

lo recojo con esto

```
function agregaRegistro(){
    var url = 'postula.php';
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:$('#formpost').serialize(),
        success: function(registro){
            $('#formulario')[0].reset();
        $("#cargando").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

y lo proceso con este PHP

```
<?php
//copy ($ruta,$destino);
    //conexión a la base de datos
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos" .mysqli_connect_error();
            }
$ide = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ide"]);          
$idp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["idp"]);          
$ida = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ida"]);
$sqli= mysqli_query($con,"select  COUNT(*) AS total from postulado where id_emp='$ide' AND id_pub='$idp' AND id_alu='$ida'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_object($sqli);
if($row->total == 0){
    // insert va aquí, y sólo se ejecuta si no hay ningún usuario con estos parametros 
$sql = "INSERT INTO postulado (id_pos,id_pub,id_emp,id_alu)
            VALUES ('', '$idp', '$ide', '$ida')";


            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {


                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                } 
                else{ 


echo " POSTULADO "; 

                    }



} else {
    echo " no ";
    }
                ?>
```

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que imprime en el boton postular ese es el boton que manda el formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talves no es la mejor manera pero ya lo solucione mando mi for a un modal y desde ay lo mando a guardar

```
function post(ide,idp,ida){
    $('#formpost')[0].reset();
        $.ajax({

        success: function(valores){
                $('#ide').hide();
                $('#idp').hide();
                $('#ida').hide();
                $('#formpost').show();
                $('#postular').show();
                $('#ide').val(ide);
                $('#idp').val(idp);
                $('#ida').val(ida);
                $('#postularm').modal({
                    show:true,
                    backdrop:'static'
                });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function postu(){
    console.log($('#formpost').serialize()  );
    var data = $('#formpost').serialize();
    var url = 'postula.php';
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:data,

        success: function(data){
            //$('#formulario')[0].reset();
        $("#cargando").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        //copy ($ruta,$destino);
            //conexión a la base de datos
                    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd");
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos" .mysqli_connect_error();
                    }
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $ide = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ide"]);          
        $idp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["idp"]);          
        $ida = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ida"]);
        $sqli= mysqli_query($con,"select  COUNT(*) AS total from postulado where id_emp='$ide' AND id_pub='$idp' AND id_alu='$ida'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_object($sqli);
        if($row->total == 0){
            // insert va aquí, y sólo se ejecuta si no hay ningún usuario con estos parametros 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO postulado (id_pos,id_pub,id_emp,id_alu)
                    VALUES ('', '$idp', '$ide', '$ida')";

                    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                        } 
                        else{ 
                          echo " POSTULADO "; 
                        }



        } else {
           echo " no ";
        }
   }
                        ?>
```

puede que al validad que solo sean llamadas de tipo post elimine ese error, la otra es modificar un archivo en el servidor que se llama .httpaccess

Comment: me sigue guardando dos veces mira la imagen

Comment: y estas seguro que no se esta llamado doble? y suponiendo que que tu campo id_pos es aunto_increment puedes poner la query asi: 
`INSERT INTO postulado (id_pub,id_emp,id_alu)
                    VALUES ('$idp', '$ide', '$ida')` aun que ese no creo que sea el error, lo otro que te comentaba tienes tu archivo .httpaccess ?

Comment: te refieres a apache access.log

Comment: no sorry escribi mal, pero el .htaccess es la abreviatura de Hypertext Access. Se trata de un archivo de configuración utilizado por servidores web basados en apache. Este tipo de archivos configura los ajustes iniciales de un programa o, como ocurre en este caso, del servidor. este por lo general se coloca en el directorio principal, es lo que se me ocurre que esta mandando doble request al archivo al mismo tiempo por eso el select que tienes de validacion no esta funcionando seria bueno que leyeras un poco de eso

Answer (score 0):

otra cosa que se me ocurrio pordia ser intentar con esto:

```
$query="INSERT INTO postulado (id_pub,id_emp,id_alu) VALUES ('$idp', '$ide', '$ida')";

    $result=$conn->query($query);
    if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "POSTULADO";
    } else {
     echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }
 $conn->close();
```

Comment: Esto si me funciono muchísimas gracias enrecio que gran paciencia gracias por tu ayuda Ivan Rangel para lo que se te ofrezca

Comment: no siempre no quiso jeje

Comment: jajajajaa por que?, si habia funcionado y luego ya no?

Comment: Exacto jajajaja estubo muy raro

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo que posiblemente te puede funcionar.

> **ADVERTENCIA:** `MySQL*` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

**Ejemplo:**

*Formulario:*

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ide = $row['id_e'];
    $idp = $row['id_p'];
    $ida = $_SESSION['id_a'];

    echo "
        <form id=formpost class=formulario name=otro onsubmit='return agregaRegistro();'>
            <input type=text name=ide id=ide value=$ide />
            <input type=text name=idp id=idp value=$idp />
            <input type=text name=ida id=ida value=$ida />

            <input type=submit name=submit id=agregar value=agregar />

        </form>

        <div id=cargando></div>
    ";
}

mysqli_free_result($result)
?>
```

*Función*

```
function agregaRegistro(){

    var url = 'postula.php';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#formpost').serialize(),
        success: function(registro){
            $('#formulario')[0].reset();
            $("#cargando").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

*postula.php*

```
<?php
//Si esta defenido el formulario y no es NULL (mediante el identificador de nuestro boton).
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //conexión a la base de datos
    $con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bd');
    //Verificar conexión.
    if (!$con) {
        exit('La conexión fallo: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

    //Obtenemos datos.
    $ide = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ide"]);          
    $idp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["idp"]);          
    $ida = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["ida"]);

    //Sentencia SELECT.
    $sqli= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id_emp from postulado where id_emp='$ide' AND id_pub='$idp' AND id_alu='$ida'");

    //Comprobamos existencia de registro.
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sqli)===0) {

        //Sentencia INSERT
        $insertar = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO postulado (id_pub,id_emp,id_alu) VALUES ('$idp', '$ide', '$ida')");

        //Comprobamos que se inserto correctamente.
        if(!$insertar) { #falso.
           printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        } else { #verdadero.
            echo " POSTULADO ";
        }

    } else {
        echo "No se inserto. Ya existen un registro en la Base de datos.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: El problema aqui es que no lo puedo sacar del while porque el formulario se va a ir imprimiendo en varios registros en el cual cada uno tiene su propio id de publicacion y de la empresa que lo publico me explico?

Comment: @ivanrangel A vale, pensaba que solo era un registro. Podrias tambien incluirlo en tu while si quieres. Te actualizo mi ejemplo, y me comentas aver.

Comment: Esta bien te lo agradesco

Comment: @ivanrangel ya te e actualizado el ejemplo añadiendo el formulario en tu `while`. A ver si te funciona ahora.

Comment: creo que con el script que tengo no funciona cual utilizas tu?

Comment: @ivanrangel ¿Te refieres al codigo en general o a algun apartado del codigo? Un problema que veo es que tambien mezclas `mysql*` con `mysqli*`, en tu conexión utilizas `mysqli` y en tu sentencia `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` utilizas `mysql`... Si vas a tener varios forumulario tambien te va mandar errores en tu HTML, ya que los ID se repiten tambien por cada registro encontrado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55638/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-ivanrangel).

Answer (score 0):

con este script modificado solo manda 1 pero ya no quiere mandar los demas formularios se queda con klos datos del primer formulario

```
function postu(){
    console.log($('#formpost').serialize()  );
    var data = $('#formpost').serialize();
    var url = 'postula.php';
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:data,
        success: function(data){
            //$('#formulario')[0].reset();
        $("#cargando").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Me alegro Iván, acepta tu respuesta como válida si fue la solución a tu problema. Que tengas suerte con tu proyecto. Un saludo.

Comment: pues que no te alegre porque mi codigo me engaño jajajaja ahora solo manda el primer formulario ya no quiere mandar los demas jajajaja

Comment: Le estas pasando el mismo ID a todos tus formularios, y eso te da error. No puedes tener en un mismo documento más de un formulario con el mismo `ID`.